# Cannot access webserver from internet Centos 6.5

Tags: linux, joomla, apache2, centos6

I have installed a CentOS 6.5 web server, now it is connected to LAN and WAN, Joomla is installed (LAMP)

I'm not able to see the webpage from internet only from LAN

I've checked

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

eth1 Internet IP

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
/etc/hosts
[public ip] [www.mywebsite.org.ec]
```

I have disabled `iptables`, but still no access.

Is there something else I can check?

SOLUTION:

There was something missing in the route table.

You have to set de WAN gateway as default instead of LAN Gateway

Comment: A question should not be resolved by writing the answer/solution into the quesiton body.  Please extract your solution from your question body and transfer it to a new answer (and explain your solution if possible).  Then edit your question to remove the answer.  If you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the web page from internet side your gateway router should direct requests for HTTP to your server. Check your NAT configuration for the gateway device. Also if there exists a firewall on that device, you should configure it to accept HTTP requests.